# Page zoom (scale) at cursor location

Tags: javascript, webview, google-chrome-app

I'm working on a Chrome App that injects Javascript into a webview (similar to an iframe). The JS listens for a right-click inside the webview, and zooms in (scales) the contents of the webview, centering the scale at the cursor location. In other words, if I were to frame StackOverflow.com inside the webview and right-click on the S.O. logo near the top left of the page, the webview should then center on the S.O. logo, with it zoomed in.

I'm getting *relatively* close, but my math (or logic) is apparently a little bit off. Here is the JS I'm injecting into the webview ("window", "document", etc. below refers to the webpage inside the webview, not the parent window)...

```
window.oncontextmenu = function (){  // when the webview content is right-clicked...
    var page = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];  // get the webview body element
    // get cursor location inside webview...
    var cursorX = event.clientX;  
    var cursorY = event.clientY; 
    // get scrollbar offset inside webview...
    var scrollX = page.scrollLeft; 
    var scrollY = page.scrollTop; 
    // scrollbar offset +  cursor location (I'm *not* sure if this is the correct logic, but it gets me fairly close)...
    var x = scrollX + cursorX; 
    var y = scrollY + cursorY; 
    page.style.transformOrigin = x + 'px ' + y + 'px';  // set CSS transform origin (the pixel location where the scales centers)
    page.style.transform = 'scale(10)';  // Zoom in 10X 
    return false; 
}
```

FYI, the size of the webview in my app will vary, depending on the end user's screen size, so I need code that takes that into consideration. If the webview was a fixed size, then I think the math would be a little easier.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to what goes wrong here? "Apparently a little bit off" leaves a lot of room for interpretation.

Comment: By "little bit off", I meant the relative location in pixels. I wound up implementing a different strategy for this particular task though, so no longer need a solution for this one. But thanks anyways!